# defined variables with links in img src - c#

Tags: c#, html, image, asp.net-core, razor

I want to define both the link and the variable in the photo src, so when I do it, it prints as `"http: //...com'/Uploads/fMlz00X.png"`. I want to print it as `http: //...com/Uploads/fMlz00X.png`, how can I do that?

So I want to print a link at the beginning of the variable, how can I do this?

I want to add link address at the beginning of variable in src. How can I do that?

```
<img alt="example image" src="....com'@item.sliderURL'">
<img alt="example image" src="....com'@item.sliderURL'">
```

Comment: Your description is unclear. Please show an example of the HTML output you want to create, I think that would help us to understand.

Comment: current output: "http: //...com'/Uploads/fMlz00X.png" must be: http: //...com/Uploads/fMlz00X.png

Comment: Well you can just remove the `'` from the code if you don't want that, because it seems you've hard coded it. e.g. `src="....com@item.sliderURL"`. But I don't see what the issue with the `"`s is - that is normally necessary to wrap an attribute value in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two solutions:

1.delete '' and add ()

```
<img alt="example image" src='....com@(item.sliderURL)' />
```

2.use @Url.Content

```
<img alt="example image" src='@Url.Content("....com" + item.sliderURL)'>
```